# Customize kendo date filter and verbiage

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to change the kendo grid filter for date columns to state only  "From" and "to". I cannot find a way to do this using MVC Razor Syntax.

```
filterable: {
extra: false, //do not show extra filters
operators: { // redefine the string operators
    string: {   
        contains: "Contains",
        startswith: "Starts With",
        eq: "Is Equal To"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Razor I guess you are using the ASP.NET MVC version, the syntax is

```
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
        .Extra(false)
        .Operators(operators => operators
            .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                .StartsWith("Starts with")
                .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")

            ))
        )
```

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-menu-customization

Comment: Thank you. I came across this, but was completely overlooking one thing. I didn't see the options i needed for dates. Then realized the example is using String type, and once i changed ".ForString" to ".ForDate" i saw my options.  -Thanks-